# Eclipse freezes when I try to open compare view

Tags: eclipse, freeze, eclipse-mars

As part of a routine code update, I was comparing my versions of several Java files with the versions from the SVN repository I use.  I noticed that one of my files was corrupted, and so I restored it from a backup.  However, now when I try to use Eclipse to compare the newly-non-corrupted file with the SVN version, Eclipse freezes.  I have tried restarting Eclipse (many times), checking for Eclipse updates, and rebooting the computer, all with no success.

I'm running Eclipse Mars.2 on Windows 7 Professional.

How do I get Eclipse to stop freezing and actually compare the files?

UPDATE: I have been able to do other things in Eclipse (such as editing code, running the Android emulator, etc.) but the compare-files function still causes it to freeze, at least with this particular file.  I don't have any other files that need comparing, so I can't test that.

Answer (score 0):

You might just make some arbitrary non-breaking changes to other files just to see whether the compare is generally broken or if it's really just that file.

Alternatively you could copy paste the file into notepad and back in case it's some odd special char that's causing the issue.